# Efficient ways to display/scroll through large R objects

Tags: r, read-eval-print-loop

I am working with large `(sparse) matrices` and large `data.frames` in `R` quite extensively. Currently I am trying to set up covariance factor matrices for factors that have a lot of levels (usually `>40`). I check if I set up the covariance factors right by doing some simple tests (e.g. by checking the dimensions or performing task-specific matrix calculations which I expect to output certain values) but I also like to look at the objects with my own eyes and check if the values are stored in the right column and row. E.g. if I expect say `2.3` at position `(i,j)` of matrix `M` I subset it accordingly and check if the correct value is at position `(i,j)`.

But a lot of times I set up things like block diagonal matrices (which can be very large) at which I also like to look. More specifically I would like to scroll through them horizontally and vertically. I usually invoke `page(object, "print")`. But this only allows me to scroll vertically and not horizontally. For `data.frames` that are wider than the current display I can use `View` or even `edit`. However neither of those are applicable to objects of e.g. class `dgCMatrix`.

Here is a little example of a sparse matrix that I would like to be able to scroll through horizontally and vertically:

```
library(Matrix)
A <- model.matrix(~rep(rep(factor(1:2),
                           each = 2),
                       times = 2800))
B <- t(as(rep(factor(1:70),
              each = 160),
          Class = "sparseMatrix")) 
C <- t(as(rep(rep(factor(1:40),
                  each = 4),
              times = 70),
          Class = "sparseMatrix"))

D <- t(KhatriRao(t(B), t(A)))
E <- t(KhatriRao(t(C), t(A)))

# This is an example of an object I would like to scroll through. 
# If your display should happen to be big enough just take the
# transpose of F:

F <- cBind(D, E)
```

Some basic info about the way I use `R`:

(1) I am using `R` from a simple `repl` session with `xterm` and `tmux` and would very much like to keep it that way. Hence, solutions involving any king of `GUI` will not work for me.

(2) The only additional package that is constantly loaded when I'm in an `R` session is the `setwidth` package which automatically resizes the width of terminal emulators. It only maximizes the possible horizontal output and hence has no negative effect (I am aware of. Also I can easily override its settings by using `options(width=10000)`; the current default maximum width of `R`.). To be sure I disabled the package on startup. All solutions I tried (`edit` and `page(object, "print")`) still will not allow me to scroll horizontally.

(3) I use `vi` editing mode in my `repl` session and I am usually scrolling using `h`, `j`, `k`, `l`.

What is the most efficient way to display such objects in `R`? I would be very happy if someone has had the same problem and found a solution to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do it is to convert to a normal matrix and use `fix`, though it may not be the most efficient:

```
F2<-as(F, "matrix")
fix(F2)
```

If you want to not see 0s, you could do something like this:

```
F2[F2==0] <- "."
fix(F2)
```

Comment: Yes, I did use this solution before. But the advantage of looking at sparse matrices is their sparsity. You don't see zeros everywhere.

Comment: @lord.garbage Check my edit to see if that helps with not seeing zeros everywhere.  It's still not ideal, but it does address your comment.

Comment: I was just hesitant in accepting your answer because `page(F, "print")` actually does exactly what I want and in a much better fashion than `View` or `fix`. The only problem is that `R` has an internal `width` limit. The maximum is `options(width=10000)`.

Comment: I actually just found out that I can recompile `R` and set a higher `width` limit. As I compile `R` from source anyway I'll just do that and post it as an additional answer.

Comment: @lord.garbage If the solution you found is better than the solution I found (or even if it isn't) consider posting it as an independent answer so that others can benefit from it.  I won't take offense if you deselect my answer and choose your own as the best answer to your question.

Comment: I think for most your solution is better because it is software independent and doesn't require recompiling `R` from source. Furthermore, recompiling `R` by resetting the limit in `Print.h` higher than `10000` is not a complete solution. If your terminal (e.g. `xterm` in my case) has some form of linewrap (soft or hard) enabled you will still end up with wrapped lines. Hence, you would need to disable this too.